# Rest Assured : handling multiple results in response?

Tags: java, automated-tests, rest-assured

When I post a request with name 'John' in my test I get several results in response:

```
<links>
<a href="http://test.com/1" id="7875a7a1" title="doctor">John Smith</a>
<a href="http://test.com/2" id="a3e51e21">John Doe</a>
....
</links>
```

My goal is to find the right John, knowing his id and find out if attribute 'title' is present. How would I achieve this with a simple given-when-then syntax? Assume I do not know in which node the desired item is.

In theory I could get a list of all nodes and check them one by one in a for loop, but that sounds ugly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this to verify that the title is doctor:

```
String id = "7875a7a1";
given().
       ...          
when().
       post("/x").
then().
       body("links.a.find { it.@id == '%s'}.@title", withArgs(id), equalTo("doctor"));
```

And like this to check if the title attribute exists:

```
String id = "7875a7a1";
given().
       ...          
when().
       post("/x").
then().
       body("links.a.find { it.@id == '%s'}.attributes().any { it.key == 'title' }", withArgs(id), is(true));
```

Comment: Thanks Johan, I also found that this could work:

`given().param("id", expectedId).expect().body(hasXPath("/links/a/@title")).when().get(request);`

but now I am stuck on how to assert the opposite - that the attribute is not shown. This time the test should pass if attribute is not shown.

Comment: If you're using my example then just change is(true) to is(false).